# Generate Client ID on deploy

Tags: jms, wildfly-8, hornetq, message-driven-bean

I have a WildFly cluster which should share all topic messages to different nodes and keep them if one node is offline.
For this case I need durable subscriper.

```
@MessageDriven(
    activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "jms/Topic"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionDurability", propertyValue = "Durable"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionName", propertyValue = "anam123e"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "clientID", propertyValue = "abcd"),
    }
)
```

I have noticed if I am using the same clientID the system is doing load-balancing. If I change the **clientID** or **subscriptionName** to an unique value it works.

So when to use a unique **clientID** and when **subscriptionName**?
My answer was, unique clientID per Node and subscriptionName per Thread on a Node.

Furthermore I want to generate a clientID based on the wildfly node name similar to:

```
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "clientID", propertyValue = "abcd-" + WildFly.getInstance().getNodeName()),
```

Is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a real simple solution available: [Property Replacement](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Java+EE+Application+Deployment+Configuration)

You need to enable it in the *standalone.xml*:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:2.0">
    <annotation-property-replacement>true</annotation-property-replacement>
    ...
</subsystem>
```

And the new annotation can look like the following:

```
@MessageDriven(
    activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "jms/Topic"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionDurability", propertyValue = "Durable"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionName", propertyValue = "aname"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "clientID", propertyValue = "abcd-${jboss.node.name}"),
    }
)
```